# git is trying to upload the file already deleted manually

Tags: git, github

I added a file in my older commit and without pushing that commit then I deleted that file from the dir. After that I did more changes and added more commits and now every time I try to push the code I face this error when I do `git push -u origin master`

```
Counting objects: 58, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (58/58), 197.83 MiB | 370.46 MiB/s, done.
Total 58 (delta 44), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (44/44), completed with 10 local objects.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 7db8d77e8595ae0da9cc34aa2ab1c4d0
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File public/uploads.zip is 197.85 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/repo-name
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repo-name'
```

The file mentioned `uploads.zip` has been deleted before manually. so this file does not exist in the dir.

When I do `git log origin/master..master` i don't even see the file in the list.

Here is the result of `git status` [link](http://prntscr.com/coh55c)

Comment: try `git rm public/uploads.zip`

Comment: I agree with @PanLong

Comment: `fatal: pathspec 'public/uploads.zip' did not match any files` the file is not even in the dir @PanLong

Comment: @PanLong I am on windows.

Comment: @Adamnick you can use your GUI file manager, just create a dummy file and use `git rm` to remove it.

Comment: @PanLong now I should again try to push?

Comment: @Adamnick You still need to commit this change. `git commit -am "remove public/uploads.zip"`

Comment: `D:\Projects\code>git commit -am "remove public/uploads.zip"
[master 6ed7227] remove public/uploads.zip
 1 file changed, 17 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)

D:\Projects\code>git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 197.83 MiB | 365.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 48), reused 0 (delta 0)` its stuck again @PanLong

Comment: It stuck but didn't give you error right, there could be another issue

Comment: looks like its again trying to upload that file as you can see the amount of data being uploaded. 300 mb @PanLong

Comment: Wait, so you don't have uploads.zip in your machine and it still uploads it?

Comment: what about adding it to your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @PanLong yes, that's why I am confused.

Comment: can you post the output of `git status`?

Comment: @PanLong added in the question.

Comment: You are not even tracking that file! Did you added other large files also? You can check by `git diff master origin/master` to see all your local changes on master branch compared with remote branch.

Comment: its just showing simple files, no big file is there not even that zip file.  @PanLong

Comment: Then it shouldn't be uploading you zip file., but any way, you can now simply delete that file. If your are sure these changes are correct, you should just push it.

Comment: what will happen if I delete the .git folder @PanLong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: All your files will still be there, but anything related to git will be lost, your git repo information, your git history etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your git repo keeps trying to upload large files, you might want and check for any tracked (and later deleted) large files.

Use [BFG Repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) and see if, in your history, you don't have some files to remove.

> Remove all blobs bigger than 10 megabytes :

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M  my-repo.git 

# or

java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
```

Comment: right now I get this error `Error: Unable to access jarfile bfg-1.12.13`

Comment: @Adamnick you can use the second form `java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git`. Of course, replace `bfg.jar` by the full path of the jar you have downloaded from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/1.12.13/bfg-1.12.13.jar

Comment: I am using the second version already, is there any other method?

Comment: @Adamnick no just use the correct path for the jar: `Unable to access jarfile bfg-1.12.13` means the cmd line does not find `bfg-1.12.13.jar`

Comment: @Adamnick and make sure to use a --mirror cloned repo, that is a bare repo, as per BFG usage instructions: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage

Comment: @Adamnick see for instance https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/33#issuecomment-86718607

Comment: this file `public/uploads.zip` does not even exist on my dir anymore but git is still uploading God knows whats happening.

Comment: @Adamnick note that you won't file any big file in your working tree: the idea of bfg is to look for big files in your history of commits. If 10MB doesn't yield anything, try 1MB.