# cleaning git history with BFG

Tags: git, github, large-files, bfg-repo-cleaner

As I recently tried to push my commits to github, I got the same error message as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804502/git-is-trying-to-upload-the-file-already-deleted-manually). I removed the files from my repository but now have to clean up the history. As advised in the answers I looked into BFG, which seems to be the solution. While reading through the [instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) it starts with using `git --mirror link-to-remote-repo`.

Now I am wondering, because I couldn't push the newest commit yet and probably my local commit history is longer than the one on github. Furthermore I am unsure as all the work I did is on a branch and not on master and how it affects my repository.

Comment: What is a question?

Comment: What I don't understand is that in order to use BFG I should do a bare clone (`--mirror`) of my remote repository. But this isn't up to date. So how is this going to work? I clean up the history of the remote mirror, but there is still "some history" about that file left in my local repository in the commits I did after the last time I pushed to github.

Comment: Ok. In case you have not big number of changes (commits) you can do this manually: 
check out new branch on the base commit; For each commit (from problematic branch) - 1) use command `git cherry-pick <SHA1> --no-commit`; 2) delete from index problematic binary file (if exist); 3) commit

Comment: Well, the branch is probably 16+ commits further than master/the last pushed commit on the remote. 
Which branch should I check out? The last one in the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual solution (based on `cheery pick`)

EDIT: Before you start please commit or stash your local changes.

Let's say we have two branches `master` and `dev` which have common commit with SHA1 = X. Branch `dev` contains commits A1, A2, ..., A16

- `git checkout dev`
- `git checkout -b new-dev`
- `git reset --hard X`

For each commit in `dev` (A1, ..., A16):

- `git cherry-pick A1 --no-commit`
- Check you index with `git status`
- Remove your problematic binary files from the index `git reset HEAD myfolder/mybinary.rpm`
- delete the file `git rm myfolder/mybinary.rpm`

Comment: So just for me to understand,
1. I create a new branch `new-dev` and do `git reset --hard X` This discards all changes of any tracked file in `new-dev`.
2. I work through the commits in `dev` using `git cherry-pick` to remove the file as you described.
 
Now I'm at my last commit. Do I merge first with `new-dev` and then with `master`? How do I get my repository back to the latest commit, just without the bad files?

Comment: After you've done all steps you have new branch `new-dev` with the "same" history as in branch `dev` minus "bad" binary files. You should see the same number commits in `new-dev` as in `dev` with the same comments. So now you should merge `new-dev` to your `master`. Later, when you are really sure that all is correct you may delete `dev` branch.

Comment: I see. But then I do `git cherry-pick` on `new-dev` and not on `dev`, or?

Comment: Worked out. I could push the `new-dev` repository to github without any issues. Only thing I didn't expect was when I checkout out `new-dev` all the uncommited changes in `dev` were gone, even after I switched back to that branch.

Comment: My mistake. `git reset --hard X` command delete all uncommitted changes. I'lll update the answer